# How would you translate "rank" or "level" to Latin?

Tags: vocabulary

In English, we can talk about people or things as being at a certain level or rank. For example, in gaming systems, you might have a character or ability that is level 10, or level 20, etc.

What would be the best way to express this in Latin? My first thoughts are *ordo*, *locus*, or *gradus*. The first two seem more applicable for the person themselves, while *gradus* seems a better choice for things rather than people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Middle Ages, it was fairly common to use *gradus* to refer to distinct levels of rank within organizations, such as the church. You can consult a medieval lexicon such as [DMLBS](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/gradus) for more references. I'll just give one:

Aldhelmus Schireburnensis (639 – 709), De virginitate (709):

> sicque per septenos Ecclesiae gradus paulatim proficiens ad summum
> pontificatus apicem feliciter perveniret.
>
> And thus progressing one-by-one through the seven ranks of the church,
> he successfully arrived at the apex, the papacy.

Comment: If you want a non-Eccl. reference, you can add [*Gradus ad Parnassum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradus_ad_Parnassum).

Comment: Possibly of note, the modern usage of ‘degree’ as an indication of academic qualification derives from this usage, as does the usage of the term ‘degree’ in Freemasonry.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be **numerus**. according to [definition B.II of L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=numerus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059):

> number, rank, place, position, estimation, relation, class, category. (cf.: “nomen, locus, in loco, in vicem):

*In numero [+genitive] habri*: to be (considered) of a certain class. But this word is probably better fit to distinguished between classes, rather than a continuum level of the individual of some skill.